# Usage of Substring function in Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Want to populate new column using length column in sheet

df=df.withColumn("CityName",df.Address.substr(1,F.col("Length")))

but it is throwing error

TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'int'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('Calgary', 2)
], ['CityName', 'Length'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('test', f.expr('substring(CityName, 2, Length)'))
)
```